# c# Send escape sequence with PosExplorer

Tags: c#, thermal-printer

I'm trying to send escape sequence to a thermal printer (Epson TM-T20). Now I can print, but when I make this:

```
string ESC = Convert.ToString((char)27);
string logo=Convert.ToString(ESC+"|tL");
_oposPrinter.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, logo);
_oposPrinter.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "Print example\n");
_oposPrinter.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, Convert.ToString((char)27 + "|#fP"));
```

The printer only prints "Print example", the escape sequences being ignored. I supose that escape sequences are correct because I extracted them from epsonExpert documentation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I doubt there are very many people here experienced with that printer. You are much more likely to get a response via an Epson forum or by contacting them directly.

Comment: Take a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172731/ascii-raw-symbols-to-control-a-printer-from-a-txt-file) it is for a different printer, but it should be of help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with Enviroment.NewLine ?

```
_oposPrinter.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "Print example"+ Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't need this because I can feed the paper with \n too but I need to send escape sequences in order to cut the paper (ESC +"|#fP" ) or print stored logo (ESC+"|tL")